# Merging tagged template literal fragments : best algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, template-literals

I have a tagged template literal fragment builder that looks like this :

```js
function fragment(chunks, ...args) {
  return new Fragment(chunks, args);
};

class Fragment {
  constructor(chunks, args) {
    this.chunks = chunks;
    this.args = args;
  }
}
```

The idea is to being able to split tagged template literals in different parts and having a `merge` function that transforms an arbitrarily deeply nested fragment tree into a `chunks` array and an `args` array as if it was just one big tagged template literal to begin with :

```js
function f() {}
function g() {}

const part = fragment`A ${f} B`

const nested = fragment`C ${part} D ${g} E ${part}`

const [chunks, args] = merge(nested)

console.log(chunks) // ["C A ", " B D ", " E A ", " B"]
console.log(args) // [function f, function g, function f]
```

What would be the nicest and most efficient algorithm to implement `merge` ? Thank you.

Comment: Why do that afterwards in a `merge`, not just directly in the `Fragment` constructor? You wouldn't even need to deal with recursion in there.

Comment: @Bergi Because `merge` is the more general case. If I have an algorithm to merge directly in the `Fragment` constructor, then I just need to add a recursion to it to get `merge`. So one or the other solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit ugly since template literals have two [parallel arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array), but here's what I'd do:

```
function mergeInto(target, acc, {chunks: srcChunks, args: srcArgs}) {
    const {chunks: targetChunks, args: targetArgs} = target;
    for (var i=0; i<srcArgs.length; i++) {
        acc += srcChunks[i];
        if (srcArgs[i] instanceof Fragment) {
            acc = mergeInto(target, acc, srcArgs[i]);
        } else {
            targetChunks.push(acc);
            targetArgs.push(srcArgs[i]);
            acc = "";
        }
    }
    return acc + srcChunks[i];
}

function merge(fragment) {
    const chunks = [], args = [];
    chunks.push(mergeInto({chunks, args}, "", fragment));
    return [chunks, args];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another interpretation, although am not fully confident in its execution without seeing more data samples.  In short, there is no need for the `merge` function if one tackles the management of `chunks` and `args` in the `fragment` function...

```js
function fragment(chunks, ...args) {
  let chunksCopy = [];
  let argsCopy = [];
  for ( i = 0; i < args.length; i++ ) {
    if ( args[ i ] instanceof Fragment ) {
      chunksCopy[ i ] = chunks[ i ] + args[ i ].chunks[ 0 ];
      chunksCopy[ i + 1 ] = args[ i ].chunks[ 1 ] + chunks[ i + 1 ];
      //argsCopy.splice( i, 0, args[ i ].args[ 0 ] );
      argsCopy[ i ] = args[ i ].args[ 0 ];
    } else {
      if ( chunksCopy[ i ] == null ) {
        chunksCopy[ i ] = chunks[ i ];
      }
      argsCopy[ i ] = args[ i ];
    }
  }
  if ( chunksCopy[ i ] == null ) {
    chunksCopy[ i ] = chunks[ i ];
  }
  return new Fragment( chunksCopy, argsCopy );
};

class Fragment {
  constructor( chunks, args ) {
    this.chunks = chunks;
    this.args = args;
  }
}

function f() {}
function g() {}

const part = fragment`A ${f} B`;
console.log( part );

const nested = fragment`C ${part} D ${g} E ${part}`;
console.log( nested )
console.log( nested.chunks );  // ["C A ", " B D ", " E A ", " B"]
console.log( nested.args ) // [function f, function g, function f]
```

Note when using "Run code snippet", that `console.log( nested.args )` appears to show the third function argument as a reference back to the first function argument of `f()`.  For a clearer interpretation of the results, copy and run the above in browser debug mode...